# How to get all the references to function using PyDBG?

Tags: malware, debuggers

I'd like to get all the addresses in the binary that some function is called from using PyDbg. The address of the function will be supplied as a parameter.

Do I have actually to scan all the code, looking for the call that is calling that function or is there a more elegant way?

**Update:**

The function is not exported or imported.

**Update 2:**

For example **ImmDbg**  how can it find all the references and show them?

Comment: im not sure pydbg has any static analysis built into it and so i don't think it could do much more than what Igor suggested

Comment: For update 2: it does that using static analysis. Roughly the same as IDA. Disassemble the entire binary and note every immediate destination.

Comment: presumably I still do not know about **radare** capabilities, is there some "cheep" static disassembler library that can be connected to PyDbg and produce some sort of "ImmDbg" result?

Comment: @ph0sec: you shouldn't amend your question with things that *broaden* instead of narrow down the scope of it.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: So, how do you suggest to ask this question? In my opinion, this will help to understand the matter and resolve the problem I have.

Comment: @ph0sec: PyDbg exists independent of ImmunityDbg and therefore you are changing the scope of the question after we answered. On a faster-paced site those of us answering would perhaps not even notice that you changed your question like that. How about asking it in a separate question? But quite frankly I don't think you will get a much different answer. You need a proper static analysis run for what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want all the `call` instructions (and possibly fake `call`s using `push` and `jmp` and similar using opaque predicates) you won't get around static analysis ([static-analysis](/questions/tagged/static-analysis)) of the binary. And if the binary is in any way packed or encrypted that means you need to get through that layer first.

Igor's solution will be your best bet short of loading the file into a good disassembler and finding all the cross-references to the function you are interested in. But it has the limitation that Igor already pointed out.

Static analysis has to deal with a lot of ambiguities and issues when distinguishing data and code. But *good* disassemblers are fairly good at making the right guess and will offer to interactively mark items one way or the other in case of doubt.

#### Conclusion

What this means is that PyDbg is probably not the right tool for the problem at hand unless you manage to coerce it into making use of a proper full-fledged disassembler to get all cross-references. But the better choice is probably something like [radare2](http://radare.org/) and then, if you are more familiar with PyDbg, applying the gained knowledge to the debugged target in PyDbg.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand your point and I'll take a look @ radare. I'd like to understand another thing - in the main question

Comment: @ph0sec: if it's closely related, edit your question, otherwise better ask a new question :) ... it's better than changing the scope of an existing question after people answered.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put a breakpoint on the function address.
2. When hit, get the dword at `ESP` - that would be the return address.

This, obviously, will catch only the actual calls, not all potential ones.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the obvious one. But I need all of them :).